# Can we rollback the edit which we did on other question or answer? If no, then why?

Tags: discussion

I am editing some old questions to get the Archaeologist badge. And in that process, if I have edited one post and then realized that the edited detail is not enough, or I say it's not a good edit by myself, then I started looking for 'rollback', but I didn't find that.

I know that if I have done any edit on my own question or answer then I can 'rollback' to the previous version or edit. So why is it not available for that question or answer which you edit?

I know that this type of edit is get rejected by in review, but why can't we allow the user to 'rollback' the edit?

Suppose if we have 'rollback' then it saves time for the reviewer to review, and they may do some more important things.

I am adding my approved edit screenshot here:

[image]

My latest edited question with a review pending:

[image]

Comment: Can you please link the question you refer to

Comment: [the-question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16929824)

Comment: It is already rollback by moderators .

Comment: Your changes are rolled back by the reviewer

Comment: Yes sir, i know and that's a question because if i can rollback it by my self then i could save some time of moderators. @CodeLღver

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can roll back your edit by following steps:

- Go to all actions tab in your profile.
- Select the revision tab
- Select the edit link and you will get a screen there is one option.

[image]

Look at the picture; there is an option of rollback. Clicking on that you can rollback your edit.

Comment: Maybe you didn't get or you didn't see that I am not eligible for **Suggested Edits** Review so in my case it didn't show me.  please see the image in my updated question.

Comment: @ankitsuthar Maybe you can not see it because of less reputations?

Comment: yes, I know that and that's the way I asked it here sir that if I can rollback my edit then it save some time for moderators. @Jens

Comment: @ankitsuthar the suggestion made by you, you can see try with editing my this answer and got to check. you will get that.

Comment: sir i can't edit you current post it show "Suggested edits are not allowed on non-tag-wiki posts on meta sites"

Comment: Try on SO then. find a low quality post and edit that and check there.

Comment: @CodeLღver Sir here is my latest edit and it's gone for a review but it didn't show the rollback. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16932374)

Comment: i can add screen shot if you want?

Comment: @ankitsuthar ok do that

Comment: @CodeLღver sir I have added screenshot.

Comment: @ankitsuthar Yes, I checked. You are right. It is happening. Second way is you can copy previous content and then again paste but that will be again a edit. So I think there should be other option.

Comment: Thank sir @CodeLღver to understand because i just checked that I get one down vote on this question so your comment is keeping my hope that i had asked a proper question here.